# Redirect index.php to root does not work with SSL

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, ssl

I'm developing a codeigniter/php web application running on AWS. It is a LAMP stack (ubuntu).
In order to get rid of the index.php in the url I have activated mod_rewrite and used .htaccess file to solve it.

My .htacces file is the following (this is the entire file):

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
> ```

Everything was working fine and the url was not showing the index.php, not in the home page (http://www.example.com) and not in deeper ones such as http://www.example.com/home/index

Once I have added/configured SSL the redirect stopped working.
The home page would work just like before the SSL (https://www.example.com), however none of the deeper urls work. It is trying to open the "right" url (https://www.example.com/home/index), however the server is claiming /home/index cannot be found.
It looks like the rewrite rule is not working correctly, since if I type https://www.example.com/index.php/home/index it works fine.

I've googled and tried quite a few rewrite rules, however none of them did the magic...

An additional piece of information:
I'm using the Apache 2 sites-available and sites-enabled in order to route the user to the right base url (since i'm running more than one application on my instance).

The order of files is:
A.The first part of the first file is:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>       ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>
>       Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
>         ...
>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

B.The first part of the second file is:

> ```
> <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
> <VirtualHost *:443>
>   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
>
>   ServerName www.example.com
>
>   DocumentRoot /var/www/example
>         ...
>
> </VirtualHost>
> </IfModule>
> ```

Any idea? I'm not sure if it is a configuration issue or something in my application.
Any pointer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `.htacces`s file. I am also developing web application on AWS with ssl enabled like you and going smoothly.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Venkat. Unfortunately it is still does not work for me... I keep getting 404 - "Not Found. The requested URL /home/about was not found on this server." Is that your .htaccess file in its entirety?